# model form factory not displaying correctly

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using `model form set`. If i use `formset_factory` then its displaying the form [like this](http://imgur.com/n8wWG) which is correct but if i use `modelformset_factory` then its displaying all the objects from model [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq2wV.jpg) . It [should be](http://imgur.com/n8wWG). Am I missing something? thanks

form

```
class MyImageForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = MyImage
    exclude = ('test', 'user')

MyImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(MyImage, MyImageForm)
```

template

```
{% for form in formset %}
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.image }}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

{{ formset.management_form }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Django documentation on modelformset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset), you can create MyImageFormSet as you have been doing, but simply filter it afterwards (and presumably return the new modelformset).

Create the modelformset as normal:

```
MyImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(MyImage, MyImageForm)
```

But use the modelformset with an empty query, like this:

```
MyImageFormSet(queryset=MyImage.objects.none())
```